# How would you address this aggregation/reporting scenario based on RavenDB document data?

Tags: reporting, ravendb, aggregation

We're using RavenDB (2261) as the back end for a queue-based video upload system, and we've been asked to provide a 'live' SLA report on various metrics to do with the upload system.

The document format looks like this:

```
{
  "ClipGuid": "01234567-1234-abcd-efef-123412341234",
  "CustomerId": "ABC123",
  "Title": "Shakespeare in Love",
  "DurationInSeconds": 82,
  "StateChanges": [
    {
      "OldState": "DoesNotExist",
      "NewState": "ReceivedFromUpload",
      "ChangedAt": "2013-03-15T15:38:38.7050002Z"
    },
    {
      "OldState": "ReceivedFromUpload",
      "NewState": "Validating",
      "ChangedAt": "2013-03-15T15:38:38.8453975Z"
    },
    {
      "OldState": "Validating",
      "NewState": "AwaitingSubmission",
      "ChangedAt": "2013-03-15T15:38:39.9529762Z"
    },
    {
      "OldState": "AwaitingSubmission",
      "NewState": "Submitted",
      "ChangedAt": "2013-03-15T15:38:43.4785084Z"
    },
    {
      "OldState": "Submitted",
      "NewState": "Playable",
      "ChangedAt": "2013-03-15T15:41:39.5523223Z"
    }
  ],
}
```

Within each ClipInfo record, there's a collection of StateChanges that are added each time the clip is passed from one part of the processing chain to another. What we need to to is to reduce these StateChanges to two specific timespans - we need to know how long a clip took to change from DoesNotExist to AwaitingSubmission, and how long it took from DoesNotExist to Playable. We then need to group these durations by date/time, so we can draw a simple SLA report that looks like this:

[image: Mockup video upload SLA]

The necessary predicates can be expressed as LINQ statements but when I try specifying this sort of complex logic within a Raven query I just seem to get back empty results (or lots of DateTime.MinValue results)

I realise document databases like Raven aren't ideal for reporting - and we're happy to explore replication into SQL or some other sort of caching mechanism - but at the moment I just can't see any way of extracting the data other than doing multiple queries to retrieve the entire contents of the store and then performing the calculations in .NET.

Any recommendations?

Thanks,

Dylan

Comment: This can be done with a map/reduce index.  I am working on a solution for you.  When you say "today" - do you mean "from midnight to midnight UTC" or something else?  When you say "this week", do you mean "sunday through saturday UTC" or something else?

Comment: Also - which status should I take the date from for purposes of the grouping?  The first one with `OldState == "DoesNotExist"` - or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some assumptions which you may need to adjust for:

- You operate strictly in the UTC time zone - your "day" is midnight to midnight UTC.
- Your week is Sunday through Saturday
- The date you want to group by is the first status date reported (the one marked with "DoesNotExist" as its old state.)

You will need a separate map/reduce index per date bracket that you are grouping on - Daily, Weekly, Monthly.

They are almost identical, except for how the starting date is defined.  If you want to get creative, you might be able to come up with a way to make these into a generic index definition - but they will *always* end up being three separate indexes in RavenDB.

```
// This is the resulting class that all of these indexes will return
public class ClipStats
{
    public int CountClips { get; set; }
    public int NumPassedWithinTwentyPct { get; set; }
    public int NumPlayableWithinOneHour { get; set; }
    public DateTime Starting { get; set; }
}

public class ClipStats_ByDay : AbstractIndexCreationTask<ClipInfo, ClipStats>
{
    public ClipStats_ByDay()
    {
        Map = clips => from clip in clips
                        let state1 = clip.StateChanges.FirstOrDefault(x => x.OldState == "DoesNotExist")
                        let state2 = clip.StateChanges.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NewState == "AwaitingSubmission")
                        let state3 = clip.StateChanges.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NewState == "Playable")
                        let time1 = state2.ChangedAt - state1.ChangedAt
                        let time2 = state3.ChangedAt - state1.ChangedAt
                        select new
                        {
                            CountClips = 1,
                            NumPassedWithinTwentyPct = time1.TotalSeconds < clip.DurationInSeconds * 0.2 ? 1 : 0,
                            NumPlayableWithinOneHour = time2.TotalHours < 1 ? 1 : 0,
                            Starting = state1.ChangedAt.Date
                        };

        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by result.Starting
                            into g
                            select new
                            {
                                CountClips = g.Sum(x => x.CountClips),
                                NumPassedWithinTwentyPct = g.Sum(x => x.NumPassedWithinTwentyPct),
                                NumPlayableWithinOneHour = g.Sum(x => x.NumPlayableWithinOneHour),
                                Starting = g.Key
                            };
    }
}

public class ClipStats_ByWeek : AbstractIndexCreationTask<ClipInfo, ClipStats>
{
    public ClipStats_ByWeek()
    {
        Map = clips => from clip in clips
                        let state1 = clip.StateChanges.FirstOrDefault(x => x.OldState == "DoesNotExist")
                        let state2 = clip.StateChanges.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NewState == "AwaitingSubmission")
                        let state3 = clip.StateChanges.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NewState == "Playable")
                        let time1 = state2.ChangedAt - state1.ChangedAt
                        let time2 = state3.ChangedAt - state1.ChangedAt
                        select new
                        {
                            CountClips = 1,
                            NumPassedWithinTwentyPct = time1.TotalSeconds < clip.DurationInSeconds * 0.2 ? 1 : 0,
                            NumPlayableWithinOneHour = time2.TotalHours < 1 ? 1 : 0,
                            Starting = state1.ChangedAt.Date.AddDays(0 - (int) state1.ChangedAt.Date.DayOfWeek)
                        };

        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by result.Starting
                            into g
                            select new
                            {
                                CountClips = g.Sum(x => x.CountClips),
                                NumPassedWithinTwentyPct = g.Sum(x => x.NumPassedWithinTwentyPct),
                                NumPlayableWithinOneHour = g.Sum(x => x.NumPlayableWithinOneHour),
                                Starting = g.Key
                            };
    }
}

public class ClipStats_ByMonth : AbstractIndexCreationTask<ClipInfo, ClipStats>
{
    public ClipStats_ByMonth()
    {
        Map = clips => from clip in clips
                        let state1 = clip.StateChanges.FirstOrDefault(x => x.OldState == "DoesNotExist")
                        let state2 = clip.StateChanges.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NewState == "AwaitingSubmission")
                        let state3 = clip.StateChanges.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NewState == "Playable")
                        let time1 = state2.ChangedAt - state1.ChangedAt
                        let time2 = state3.ChangedAt - state1.ChangedAt
                        select new
                        {
                            CountClips = 1,
                            NumPassedWithinTwentyPct = time1.TotalSeconds < clip.DurationInSeconds * 0.2 ? 1 : 0,
                            NumPlayableWithinOneHour = time2.TotalHours < 1 ? 1 : 0,
                            Starting = state1.ChangedAt.Date.AddDays(1 - state1.ChangedAt.Date.Day)
                        };

        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by result.Starting
                            into g
                            select new
                            {
                                CountClips = g.Sum(x => x.CountClips),
                                NumPassedWithinTwentyPct = g.Sum(x => x.NumPassedWithinTwentyPct),
                                NumPlayableWithinOneHour = g.Sum(x => x.NumPlayableWithinOneHour),
                                Starting = g.Key
                            };
    }
}
```

Then when you want to query...

```
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

var today = now.Date;
var dailyStats = session.Query<ClipStats, ClipStats_ByDay>()
                        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Starting == today);

var startOfWeek = today.AddDays(0 - (int) today.DayOfWeek);
var weeklyStats = session.Query<ClipStats, ClipStats_ByWeek>()
                         .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Starting == startOfWeek);

var startOfMonth = today.AddDays(1 - today.Day);
var monthlyStats = session.Query<ClipStats, ClipStats_ByMonth>()
                          .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Starting == startOfMonth);
```

In the results, you will have *totals*.  So if you want percent averages for your SLA, simply divide the statistic by the count, which is also returned.